# Does the official Office 2010 download contain SP2?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-2010, service-pack, slipstream

Does the latest original Office 2010 download, from the Microsoft website, contain SP2? I'm looking for an answer on this question, but I can't seem to find it.

I've tried to slipstream SP2 (+ all other updates after SP2) into my Office 2010 image, but now my 'Updates' folder is full of junk. Also, there is an .MSP in it to automate the installation. I don't know if this has effect on the installation on the updates?

Now I want to start with a clean image. So, does the latest download include SP2?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried checking here: https://www7.downloadoffice2010.microsoft.com/usa/registerkey.aspx?culture=EN-US&ref=backup&country_id=US ?

Comment: Yes it does. I just had a look at my MSDN subscription. The ISO includes SP2.

Comment: Thank you. But the trial doesn't seem to contain the SP (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ee390818.aspx)?

Comment: Hmmm.. have you tried the first link?

Comment: Yeah, I can't download it with my volume license key.